# To divide 2 rows using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code to divide two rows in excel using vba.I got an overflow error.

```
    Private Sub Rated_Advances_Total_Advance()
    Const FOLDER As String = "C:\SBI_Files\"
    Const cStrWSName As String = "Rated Advances to Total Advance"
   Const sourceName As String = "Credit Risk Components"
   On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   Dim i As Integer
   Dim fileName As String



  'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("A4:C9").ClearContents
'  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("A12:C17").ClearContents
 ' ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Range("A19:C29").ClearContents


   P = 4
  j = 1

fileName = Dir(FOLDER, vbDirectory)
Do While Len(fileName) > 0

    If Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "xls" Then
    i = i + 1
    Dim currentWkbk As Excel.Workbook
    Set currentWkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)


    'Entity wise consolidation'

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(P, j).Value = Left(currentWkbk.Name, Len(currentWkbk.Name) - 4)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(P, j).Font.Bold = True

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cStrWSName).Cells(P, 2).Value = currentWkbk.Sheets(sourceName).Cells(24, 3).Value / currentWkbk.Sheets(sourceName).Cells(27, 3).Value
```

(I got an Overflow error here)

```
    P = P + 1
    currentWkbk.Close
    End If
    fileName = Dir
Loop
Rated_Advances_Total_Advance
ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `P` when the error occurs? Is it possible that the `Integer` type is [**overflown**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx)? Change the declaration from `Integer` to `Long` and give it a quick try

Comment: @mehow For the first P itself it shows an error.I tried using long it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

If your value is greater than 15 digits it will cause an overflow if you are trying to use it as an integer.

```
Dim myValue As Long

myValue = Cells(.....).Value
```